# HTTPS запросы с алгоритмами ГОСТ. Для начинающих

Tags: .net, ssl, https, best-practice, гост

Есть задача общения с государственной структурой по API через https с защитой соединения алгоритмами ГОСТ-2012 
(ssl_protocols: TLSv1 ssl_ciphers: GOST2012-GOST8912-GOST8912)

Основной проект на C#.
Раньше для взаимодействия с различными API использовали в разных ситуациях  WebRequest, ServiceReference, WinHTTPRequest,  а также MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.

### Вопрос к знатокам:

Кто уже сталкивался с подобными проблемами.
Какой лучший и кратчайший путь для понимания и организации общения с этим API по https, а также для подписывания файлов гост-сертификатами?  Какие технологии?

Информации по теме в интернете пугающе мало.
Есть некоторая информация по подписыванию, и почти нет про https + гост.

Нашел некоторую информацию про Крипто-Про NET, также какую-то информацию про OpenSSL  (сам ни разу ни тем, ни другим не пользовался  - поэтому прошу помощи, чтобы не залезть в тупиковую ветвь при попытке что-то понять)

(Может есть какие-то готовые решения в виде библиотек либо примеры. Любые подсказки приветствуются)

P.S. А может быть всё проще и нужно просто установить/настроить какого-нибудь посредника между нашей программой и удаленным сервером таким образом чтобы слать https запросы прямиком на него обычными WebRequest-ами?

Comment: Могу сказать, что GOST2012 это боль и страдания - нет документации, нет примеров, нет специалистов. Можно задать на форуме КриптоПро, они долго, но отвечают. Либо сделать связку: Nginx + ГОСТ2012 для входящего трафика и cURL + ГОСТ2012 для исходящего. Вот [статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/353534/), в конце есть ссылка на докер-образ. Я бы использовал именно так и потратил вырученное время на что-то более стоящее.

Answer (score 1):

Помогла переустановка Крипто-Про CSP (что интересно, триальной с истекшим сроком).
Стандартный C# HttpWebRequest стал подключаться по https.

Другими словами, насколько я понял, при установке Крипто-Про CSP, приложения Windows работают с https / гост  без вмешательства со стороны разработчика.