# Ошибка "Could not connect to host" при интеграции с ГИС ЖКХ (Laravel 8, php 7)

Tags: php, laravel

*Доброго времени суток!*

Перед мной стоит задача настроить интеграцию с ГИС ЖКХ с помощью SOAP API. Я использую фреймворк **Laravel 8 на php 7**.

Для начала я хотел просто подключиться к серверу и получить от него ответ в виде ошибок авторизации или Bad Request 404.

Я нашел на офф сайте [документацию API](https://dom.gosuslugi.ru/filestore/publicDownloadServlet?context=contentmanagement&uid=d0bcd96c-2d8a-43a8-a2af-e7a0f1f40a3a&mode=view) в форматах WSDL и XSD. Так как ссылки на WSDL нет, я предположил, что всю папку необходимо скопировать в проект и **обращаться к локальному WSDL файлу** на сервере.

```
$client = new SoapClient(realpath(storage_path($this->wsdl)));

return $client->exportDebtRequests([]);
```

При попытке отправки запроса в строке

```
return $client->exportDebtRequests([]);
```

Возникает ошибка **"Could not connect to host"**.

К сожалению в открытом доступе мне удалось найти только один [хороший пример на Yii (php)](https://github.com/opengkh/gisgkh-yii2-example), попытался реализовать подключение аналогичным образом, но это не помогло. Надеялся на то, что указание дополнительных полей в `options` и `headers` поможет, но я так понимаю, что дело вообще не в этом.

```
$wsdl = "gis_api/debt-requests/hcs-debt-requests-service-async.wsdl";
$location = "https://api.dom.gosuslugi.ru/ext-bus-debtreq-service/services/DebtRequestsAsync";
//    $location = "https://sit01.dom.test.gosuslugi.ru:10081/ext-bus-debtreq-service/services/DebtRequestsAsync"; // тестовый location из документации

set_time_limit(0); // снятие ограничения по времени ожидания

        $client = new SoapClient(
            realpath(storage_path($this->wsdl)),
            [   "wsdl" =>realpath(storage_path($this->wsdl)), // путь к wsdl
                "username" => '******************',
                "password" => '******************',
                "location" => $this->location, // location сервера, который был взят из указанного wsdl файла
                "sslKey" => realpath(storage_path('gis_api/cert.key')), // ssl ключ
                "sslCert" => realpath(storage_path('gis_api/cert.pem')), // ssl сертификат
                "caInfo" => realpath(storage_path($this->caInfo)), // путь к файлу Квалифицированного сертификата ключей проверки электронной подписи ИС

                "debug_handle" => null,
                "senderId" => "********-****-****-****-************", // Идентификатор поставщика данных
                "orgPPAGUID" => "********-****-****-****-************" // Дата отправки пакета
            ]);


        // объект $header содержит 5 полей в соответствии с документацией
        $header = new RequestHeader(); // отдельный класс для заголовков
        $header->IsOperatorSignature = true; // Используется подпись оператора ИС
        $header->SenderID = '********-****-****-****-************'; // Идентификатор поставщика данных
        $header->orgPPAGUID = '********-****-****-****-************'; // Идентификатор зарегистрированной организации
        $header->MessageGUID = Helper::guid(); // Идентификатор сообщения
        $header->Date = (new \DateTime())->format(\DateTime::ATOM); // Дата отправки пакета


        $client->__setSoapHeaders(new \SoapHeader("http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/base/", 'RequestHeader', $header));

        return $client->exportDebtRequests([]); // ошибка возникает именно в момент запроса
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Если кто-то уже интегрировался с ГИС ЖКХ, посмотрите, пожалуйста, правильно ли указаны `wsdl` и `location`?
Что интересно, если использовать тестовый `location` запрос проходит медленнее, но результат тот же, то есть какие-то попытки подключения все же происходят.

Раньше аналогичным образом подключались к РТС тендеру проблем не возникало. Только в случае с РТС передавали основную информацию в теле запроса.

Comment: Проверьте установление [защищённого соединения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1132188/curl-php-windows-%D0%93%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%A22012), подозреваю что у вас не установлены [GOST SSL механизмы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040804/https-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%93%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%A2-%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85) - в государственных информационных системах используются изменённые протоколы SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась менее тривиальной, чем я описывал.
В своем проекте, я скопировал все зависимости из **"примера на Yii"**, включая конфигурации и тестовые ключи, и обратился к имеющемуся методу. Надеялся, что они будут работать, несмотря на то, что проект успел немного устареть.

Написанный там модуль действительно использовал гостовские алгоритмы шифрования, которые предоставляет библиотека для openssl, как и сказал [Daniel Protopopov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223020/daniel-protopopov)
Однако, если верить [одному из форумов](https://www.cryptopro.ru/forum2/default.aspx?g=posts&t=8544) этот способ устарел. Поэтому **код из "примера" устарел**, но все еще может пригодиться для формирования запросов.

В результате алгоритм отработал для этого использовался самописный класс `LocalSopaClient` из "примера" с openssl под капотом и выдал таймаут запроса.

Касательно защищенного соединения необходимо настраивать [ГОСТ с TLS на nginx/Apahe](https://www.cryptopro.ru/products/csp/tls/gost-nginx-apache). Есть [пример настройки](https://support.cryptopro.ru/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/333/0/sbork-i-nstrojjk-nginx-c-podderzhkojj-gost-tls) для nginx на офф. сайте КриптоПро. На данный момент я использую Apache, так что буду разбираться в ГОСТ с TLS на Apache или переносить проект на nginx.